# Exclude data from tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to exclude a specific text inside an html `span` tag.  In the given example below I just wanted to fetch all `test2` text from `span` with `class` under `a-list-item`.

my code:

```
<span class="a-list-item">test1</span>
<span class="a-list-item">test2</span>
<span class="a-list-item">test2</span>
```

my code: `tag = tag.find_all("span", {"class" : "a-list-item"})`

How to get all `test2` only. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Beautiful Soup.  In Beautiful Soup 4.7+, this is easy to do just by using `select` instead of `find_all`.  You can use `:contains()` wrapped in `:not()` to exclude spans that contain specific text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
markup = '''
<span class="a-list-item">test1</span> 
<span class="a-list-item">test2</span> 
<span class="a-list-item">test2</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
print(soup.select("span.a-list-item:not(:contains(test1))"))
```

Output

```
[<span class="a-list-item">test2</span>, <span class="a-list-item">test2</span>]
```

Comment: I didn't realise we could also do this with 4.7. I am loving 4.7 +

Comment: Yeah, for the most part, the selectors are from the spec, but I did add a little non standard stuff that I've seen adopted in other libraries. One of these days, I plan on adding a way to search contents with regex, but I haven't settled yet on how I want that to look.

Comment: I don't see deep combinator (though I believe this is deprecated from standard). Is there a way for dealing with iframes?

Comment: Currently, I don't think I prevent searching in iframes. Maybe I should, but I don't currently. I don't restrict cross site elements, for better or for worse. I assume if a "deep" selector ever gets finalized, you may see Soup Sieve adopt it and change behavior in this regard, but unless I hear complaints about iframe behavior, I might just leave things like they are now.

Comment: If nothing, it is an area I'll look closer into in the future.  I don't think BeautifulSoup even parses things differently in an iframe, even if the doctype is different. It definitely doesn't use a different parser. Selector leakage into an iframe may be a problem for some though. If I do change things, at the very least I would add a custom deep combinator until something officially surfaces.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to complain if it currently handles iframes with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with applying an xpath to exclude containing `test1`

```
//span[@class='a-list-item' and not(contains(text(), 'test1'))]
```

E.g.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
# url = ''
# tree = html.fromstring( requests.get(url).content)
h = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span class="a-list-item">test1</span> 
  <span class="a-list-item">test2</span> 
  <span class="a-list-item">test2</span>
 </body>
</html>
'''
tree = fromstring(h)
items = [item.text for item in tree.xpath("//span[@class='a-list-item' and not(contains(text(), 'test1'))]")]
print(items)
```

---

Or test each css qualifying node (based on tag and class) text value

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

h = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <span class="a-list-item">test1</span> 
  <span class="a-list-item">test2</span> 
  <span class="a-list-item">test2</span>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(h, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('span.a-list-item') if  'test1' not in item.text]
print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression `re` to find specific text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = '''
<span class="a-list-item">test1</span> 
<span class="a-list-item">test2</span> 
<span class="a-list-item">test2</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('span',text=re.compile("test2"))
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
test2
test2
```